# Why when I use GitLab through a proxy, the interface without layout

Tags: gitlab, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

Why when I use GitLab through a proxy, the interface without layout?

[image]

Apache conf:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a reverse proxy, see [this issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8421):

> I don't know how your apache proxy pass is configured. I assume you're using something like:

```
ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8880
ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8880
```

> You can define how the proxy should act within a "virtual subfolder", try following:

```
ProxyPass /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:8880
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:8880
```

Note that GitLab must be configured to run in a subfolder.
[`config/application.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/c99e9edce7fa71ad53cb35e3bac2afe4646d1ebd/config/application.rb#L55-L67) does include the following instructions:

```
# Relative url support
# Uncomment and customize the last line to run in a non-root path
# WARNING: We recommend creating a FQDN to host GitLab in a root path instead of this.
# Note that following settings need to be changed for this to work.
# 1) In your application.rb file: config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
# 2) In your gitlab.yml file: relative_url_root: /gitlab
# 3) In your unicorn.rb: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
# 4) In ../gitlab-shell/config.yml: gitlab_url: "http://127.0.0.1/gitlab"
# 5) In lib/support/nginx/gitlab : do not use asset gzipping, remove block starting with "location ~ ^/(assets)/"
#
# To update the path, run: sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
#
# config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
```

Comment: @archi_sova do you have change the relative root url in  `gitlab.yml`? (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L43)

Comment: no, I have not changed anything.

here so works: http://space1c.ru:81/ ,

but this is what does not work (proxy): http://gitlab.space1c.ru/

Comment: @archi_sova I have completed my answer

Comment: @archi_sova OK. I ma not sure to do reverse proxy without using a subfolder though.